# Curve modifier issues

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

[image]

Here is the problem, when I use curve modifier. How can I fix it?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, you need to be more specific with your questions. People can see something is wrong, but without detail they can't tell what.

Comment: Mk... When I add a modifier, istead of normal ruffles, I get this. I had the same problem with top ruffles, but I just needed to rotate ruffles. I don't know how to make bottom ruffles normal and I don't understand why this happens